# Neo4j Browser changes not reflected when access DB via api

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j 3.5 docker image on digital ocean. When I use the neo4j browser to make changes to the DB those changes are not reflected when the DB is queried by the application. I have restarted both the DB and the App to no avail. Can someone tell me why this is happening and how do you get them in sync.

Comment: You'll need to add more information about how you're querying in your app, you may want to check that it's looking at the same database as your browser. Changes made to the db from the browser are made to the db itself, so whatever is applied is committed and should be in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Docker file store is not persistent unless you have defined a volume (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).  So when u restart docker, your updates are lost.  But while your docker image is running it should be ok.
What is your "Application"

Comment: I actually have the db persisted with a volume and didn't restart the container....I have two containers (app and db) ..with the app accessing the db via the const driver = neo4j.driver(config.neo4jURL, neo4j.auth.basic(config.neo4jUSER, config.neo4jPASS)); where the neo4jURL is the bolt connection with the relevant IP address...the same as that used in the browser. I also found it strange...so i will continue my reseach.